# python conversion format sql string

Tags: python, oracle, format

Because to deal with static sql into dynamic sql, so need to use python conversion format, for example

```
DROP TABLE TABLE_NAME PURE;
CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME NOLOGGING AS
SELECT DUMMY USER_ID FROM DUAL;
CREATE INDEX I_TABLE_NAME_USER_ID ON TABLE_NAME(USER_ID) NOLOGGING;
```

I want to convert the format to:

First determine whether there is a “drop table” and then remove the data, replaced

```
V_TAB_NAME: = 'TABLE_NAME';
IF (F_DROP_TAB (V_TAB_NAME) = 1) THEN
V_SQL: = '
```

The final result is shown as

```
V_TAB_NAME := 'TABLE_NAME ';
IF (F_DROP_TAB(V_TAB_NAME) = 1) THEN
SJ_SQL := '
CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME NOLOGGING AS
SELECT DUMMY USER_ID FROM DUAL';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SJ_SQL;
COMMIT;
END IF;
SJ_SQL := '
CREATE INDEX I_TABLE_NAME_USER_ID ON TABLE_NAME (USER_ID) NOLOGGING';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SJ_SQL;
```

It may be a bit difficult to understand, but I hope someone can give me a little string to iterate over and judge the modified example or idea. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take tour at https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simple way to insert variables into SQL statements:

```
table = 'mytable'
col1 = 'name'
col2 = 'age'

statement = 'select {}, {} from {};'.format(col1, col2, table)
```

Is this what you're looking for? If not, i don't really understand the question.